# Mapping a new view to an existing resource...how do I create /resource/number/foobar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

I have built a Ruby on Rails (2.3.8) application that allows users to track their workouts. In addition, if a user is a gym owner, they can create a gym (in my case called a Box) in my app. A box filters site wide activity to just members of that box (accomplish through a membership association but that isn't important for this).

A Box lives in a Boxes resource and is accessed in my app at /boxes/14 as you would expect. I now want to create a `leaderboard` for each box that would ideally live at `/boxes/14/leaderboard` and only display activity from box 14 (of course 14 is an example number). The leaderboard doesn't need to be a full resource because I am simply filtering activity through named_scopes.

For some reason I haven't run into a situation like this before. What is the best way to accomplish this within the framework? I have tried creating a method in the `boxes_controller` and mapping the route to `/boxes/leaderboard` but of course that restfully looks for a Box with id = leaderboard.

Any ideas? Or am I missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to add a member route for this scenario. Add something like this in your routes.rb:

```
map.resources :boxes, :member => { :leaderboard => :get }
```

That will result in an additional route looking like this:

```
leaderboard_box GET   /boxes/:id/leaderboard    {:controller=>"boxes", :action=>"leaderboard"}
```

And that will be routed to an action called leaderboard in the BoxesController.